# tiny-aes-c AES CTR 128 cuts off decrypted string in some cases

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I've been trying to use the AES CTR 128 from tiny-aes-c (https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) to encrypt a randomly generated token, and it works, but not all the time. In some cases the retrieved string after encrypting and decrypting is cut off at some point. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "token_auth.h"
#include "aes.h"

uint8_t * create_token() {
  static char charset[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  uint8_t *token = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * (TOKEN_LENGTH + 1));
  int i = 0;

  srand ( time(NULL) );

  for (i = 0; i < TOKEN_LENGTH; i++) {    
    int pos = rand() % (int)(strlen(charset) - 1);
    token[i] = (int) charset[pos] - 0;
  }

  token[TOKEN_LENGTH] = 0;

  return token;
}

int main() {
  uint8_t key[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };
  uint8_t iv[16] = { 0x0F, 0x0E, 0x0D, 0x0C, 0x0B, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };
  uint8_t *in = create_token();
  printf("\nInput: %s\nSize: %d", (char *) in, strlen((char *) in));

  struct AES_ctx ctx;
  AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
  AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, strlen((char *) in));

  AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
  AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, strlen((char *) in));
  printf("\nDEC: %s\n", (char *) in);
  return 0;
}
```

TOKEN_LENGTH is 128. As an example of the behavior, the string `NM5DlWyYInbeNtEWhBxGCdEjHSv2I6FzTMffJNgudrL2UsYe6zVJMA3wvAyhHeQD18UMXckcF8gBAfPGQNqGqwdW9MgS39w7huVfIgtoqJ212SKSIdBaJP9VErOJAmQT` comes out `NM5DlWyYInbeNtEWhBxGCdEjHSv2` after being encrypted and decrypted. I'm not really good at C, so it might just well be a problem with something else I've done, but at this point I'm lost. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to `AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer` encrypts the buffer in place in CTR mode.

The buffer still has the same size (128 in your case), but can contain NUL bytes.

The strlen call in the second call of AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer for decryption can therefore result in a length < 128 if the buffer contains a NUL byte.
By the way: It works in cases where the encryption does not result in a NUL byte in the buffer.

So if you call it with TOKEN_LENGTH as the `length` parameter decryption will give the original string again:

```
AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, in, TOKEN_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does solve it. Let's say I need to put the encrypted output to a file, I need to be aware of it's size to do so and to retrieve it at another point as well?

Comment: Yes, you could for example use the size of the file, only strlen cannot be used because the encrypted data may contain a NUL byte which is the string end terminator for a C string.